# How do I apply function to second column of data?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have data which looks like this: `{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},....}`. I need to apply a function to each element in the second column `{b,d,f,....}` and leave the first column unchanged.

What is the proper way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Or `{#1,f[#2]}&@@@{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f],...}` if you like arcane symbols.

Comment: @Kuba `MapAt[f, m, {All, 2}]` works perfectly, thanks!